# Qt How to stop shift-tab from changing widget focus?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set up a text edit that does the shift+tab remove indentation thing that code editors do; but i can't respond to shift+tab because it changes the widget focus.

I tried overriding the event function in the main window and that didn't work; then i tried event filters on all widgets and that didn't work; then i tried overriding QApplication::notify like so:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyApplication(int argc, char *argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv) { }
    virtual ~MyApplication() = default;

    bool    notify(QObject * o, QEvent *e) override
    {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent* k = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(e);

            if (k->key() == Qt::Key_Tab && dynamic_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(focusWidget()))
            {
                // filter tab out
                return false;
            }
        }

        return QApplication::notify(o, e);
    }
};
```

And that didn't work; and additionally it crashes in QCoreApplication::arguments unless I run the application from inside valgrind for some reason.

Regardless I'm out of ideas, how can i stop shift+tab from changing focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement the desired behavior in Qt's included `qtbase/examples/widgets/widgets/lineedits` example program, by inserting the following code into `main.cpp`, just above `int main(int, char **)`:

```
class BackTabFilter : public QObject
{
public:
   BackTabFilter(QObject * parent) : QObject(parent)
   {
      qApp->installEventFilter(this);
   }

   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * e)
   {
      if ((e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)&&(static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e)->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab))
      {
         QLineEdit * le = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit *>(qApp->focusWidget());
         if (le)
         {
            le->setText(le->text() + " Bork!");
            return true;  // eat this event
         }
      }
      return QObject::eventFilter(watched, e);
   }
};
```

.... and then adding this line into `main()` itself (just below the `QApplication app(argc,argv);` line):

```
BackTabFilter btf(NULL);
```

With these changes, pressing shift-Tab while the focus is on one of the `QLineEdits` in the GUI causes the word "Bork!" to be appended to the `QLineEdit`'s text, rather than having the widget-focus change.